# Redis performance

Tags: python, redis

I'm learning Redis and trying to measure its time performance. In this setup I set 5 000 000 keys and measured the time for each unique operation.

I have got the following plot (x-label is the number of operations (set), y-label is the time in milliseconds):

[image]

I'm noticing that the performance of Redis is going extremely down. I have also measured the performance with 1 000 000  keys:

[image]

I can monitor the constant areas with bad performance. Anyway the operating time goes down after some interval of time.

My question is if somebody has done similar researches in the area of Redis performance, could he/she discuss these results. For me it is very interesting and important to understand the reason the server does such "time jumping" and how I can improve its performance.

If somebody needs my Python-code:

```
def setKeyValue(key, value):
    assert (key != None), "Please, get a key"
    redis_server.set(key, value);

def loopKeyValues(number):
    timeUse = []
    start_tot = time.time()
    for x in range(number):
        start = time.time()
        #setHashKeyValue('mydata',x, x**2)
        setKeyValue(x, x**2)
        end = time. time()
        timeUse.append(end-start)
    end_tot = time.time()
    time_total = end_tot - start_tot
    plt.plot(timeUse)
    plt.ylabel("time")
    plt.show()
    return time_total;
```